# Neatest way of preserving application settings between upgrades?

Tags: c#

Our product has several user-defined settings, which to date have been stored using the project's Settings variables, e.g.

```
public string MySetting {
  get { return Settings.Default.MySetting; }
  set { 
    Settings.Default.MySetting = value;
    Settings.Default.Save();
  }
}
```

That works fine - but it has the unfortunate characteristic that if you uninstall the app and reinstall a newer version (no direct upgrade path exists - don't ask), all the settings are lost.

I can think of a few ways of achieving this, but they all seem a bit kludgy to me.  What do you think is the neatest way of preserving user-defined application settings between uninstalling & reinstalling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, there are two ways I can think of that could accomplish this.  The first is simply storing an XML/INI/JSON/whatever file in the user's AppData folder.  This would place the file out of the path for the application which means you could easily go get it again.  You can find the AppData folder like so:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

The other place that would be good for this type of data is the registry.  The .NET framework has pretty good support for doing this.  There's a lot of documentation out there on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzb96fk.aspx) and [other places](http://coders-project.blogspot.com/2008/06/writing-registry-keys.html) to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I know that for ClickOnce applications, a neat feature is to use a user setting to indicate whether an update is required set to `true` by default. Then, for example in `Program.cs`, you could this:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.SettingsUpgradeRequired)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Properties.Settings.SettingsUpgradeRequired = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Would this work in your case even if you do not use ClickOnce as your deployment method?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom action to the UnInstall that asks the user if he wants to keep the user settings or to delete all data.

If the user decides to keep the settings, you can keep a settings file in the installation path that keeps all the parameters, and add a custom action to the Install that replaces the settings on installation with the old file's settings.

You can also add the values to the registy, and check for them in the installation.